# Who can finance Hajj for parents?

Tags: practical-islam, hajj

Can a daughter finance hajj for her parents? I am single and have no financial obligations towards a husband nor any children to take care of. Hajj is for both my mom and dad. Can I provide the money they need to go and perform hajj?

Comment: What makes you think there's a problem with that?

Comment: I think this is our duty over our parents :)

Comment: @G.Bach I just want to make sure. My dad something along the lines that my husband and kids have a right to my earnings, and not my parents. I want to be certain that I can finance my parents' hajj.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The validity of a person's Hajj does not depend on the money being earned by themselves<sup>[1](https://islamqa.info/en/36990),</sup><sup>[2](http://www.islamweb.net/emainpage/index.php?page=showfatwa&Option=FatwaId&Id=83655)</sup>. There is no restriction on you regarding how you spend your wealth; spending it on a gift for your parents, that will be beneficial to their religion, is probably one of the better avenues you can spend it on.